# ArrayList of Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi, I want to display the last `Bitmap` from a list of bitmaps to an `ImageView`. Here is my code:

```
SubImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SubImageView);
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmapArray.add(myBitMap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(bitmapArray.size() > 0)
{
  int index = bitmapArray.size() -1;
  Bitmap lastbitmap = bitmapArray.get(index);

  SubImageView.setImageBitmap(lastbitmap);
}
```

Comment: `textview.setText(""+index);`

Comment: now its working...When i am trying to display just index, i am getting error what was the reason.?

Comment: When i am trying to display i am getting error?what you tried?

Comment: I tried to display Just "index" like textview.setText(index);

Comment: you have to set String not int...because its parameter is string